# Unknown property on TransitionGroup - React Animation

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error "warning.js:36 Warning: Unknown props `onExited`, `appear`, `enter`, `exit` on  tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see ...
    in div (created by TripFilteredList)
    in div (created by TransitionGroup)
    in TransitionGroup (created by TripFilteredList)
    in div (created by TripFilteredList)
    in TripFilteredList (created by TripSortedList)
    in div (created by TripSortedList)
    in TripSortedList (created by TripFinder)
    in div (created by TripFinder)
    in TripFinder"

I am using

```
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup';


        <TransitionGroup component="div" childFactory={child => child} >
            <div className={`cards ${display === 'other' ? 'search-results__other-content' : ''}`}>

                {display === 'row' &&
                    tripFilteredList.map((data, index) => <TripRow key={index} {...data} />)
                }

            </div>
        </TransitionGroup>
```

The Trip Row Code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { Fade } from '../../components';

    export default class TripRow extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                animationTrigger: false
            };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.setState({
                animationTrigger: true
            });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.setState({
                animationTrigger: false
            });
        }

        render() {
            const { title, id, thumbnailUrl, startLocation, endLocation, price, departureDate, summary, duration, countries, lastSeats, bestValue } = this.props;
            const style = {
                backgroundImage: `url(${thumbnailUrl})`
            };
            return (
                <Fade in={this.state.animationTrigger}>
                    <div className="trip-finder__card-row">
                          some content here
                    </div>
                </Fade>

            );
        }


    }
```

And also Fade class

```
    import CSSTransition from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransition';

    import React from 'react';

    const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => {

        return (

            <CSSTransition
                {...props}
                timeout={{enter: 500,exit: 500}}
                classNames="fade"
            >
                {children}
            </CSSTransition >
        );
    };

    export default Fade;
```

The Fade class is a generic class and is used in other places in the project as well.
I have a Fade component which basically renders children (list rows). Anyone knows whats this warning for and how can I fix it?

Here is the css

```
    .fade-enter,
    .fade-appear,
    .fade-exit {
        transition: all 500ms;
    }
    .fade-enter,
    .fade-appear {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .fade-enter-active,
    .fade-appear-active {
        opacity: 1
    }
    .fade-exit {
        transition: all 500ms;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .fade-exit-active {
        opacity: 0
    }
```

Comment: can you post the definition of `TripRow`?

Comment: @free-soul updated the code

Answer (score 3):

Resolved! Transition (TripRow) component needs to be the direct children of the Transition group.

```
tripFilteredList.map((data, index) => {
    return (
        <TransitionGroup appear={true} key={index}>
            <Fade in={this.state.transitionFlag}>
                <TripCard {...data} />
            </Fade>
        </TransitionGroup>
    )
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain by direct children or a simple example of how you solved this. I'm running into the same problem.